# C++: Getting the range between two months/years

Tags: c++

In class, we're doing an assignment to get the range between two dates using months and years as input.

My process code is as follows:

```
    int totalMonths1 = (year * MONTHS_IN_YEAR) + month;
    int totalMonths2 = (year2 * MONTHS_IN_YEAR) + month2;
    int range;

    if(totalMonths1 > totalMonths2)
    {
        range = totalMonths1 - totalMonths2;
    }

    if(totalMonths1 < totalMonths2)
    {
        range = totalMonths2 - totalMonths1;
    }
```

With const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12.

This tells me the *difference* between the two dates, but not the range. If I add 1 to the result, it's the correct range according to my professor's example program, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to get the range instead of doing "difference + 1".

Comment: What if `totalMonths1 == totalMonths2`?

Comment: You are looking for a simpler expression than `a - b + 1`?

Comment: use `range=abs(totalMonths1 - totalMonths2)+1`

Comment: @zenith I just rewrote the lines, I forgot to add the || totalMonths1 == totalMonths2 to the first if statement.

Comment: @Nemo My professor is super anal about everything. If I use + 1, he'll mark me down for not using a const int for 1, and probably for using that at all.

Comment: @Mikhail Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use absolute value. I have to use if statements. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll use abs() in the future.

Comment: Why the "range" between today and today is 1? Maybe I just dont get it... when you make the simple convention that with the date you always mean the first of the month then `range=difference`. If the prof didnt really specify that the first date is meant to be the 1st and the second date is supposed to be the last of the month, I would try to convince him that he is talking nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It doesnt get any simpler/better than `a - b + 1`. Unfortunately, anything else is over-complicating the solution and unnecessary.